# Double notfication on Yearling Badge. Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Tags: support

Today in my notification box I received the following:

[image: yearlingx2]

I found this confusing in a couple different ways.

1) My [history page](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/67643/elder-geek?tab=activity&sort=all&page=6) indicates no activity prior to May 14th here on U&L.

2) I was notified twice.

I understand that the Yearling badge can be awarded multiple times but was under the impression that it's supposed to be awarded on the annual anniversary date. After searching diligently (granted I didn't check every bug post) I'm still completely baffled by this.

I reviewed [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/68258#68258) as well as [Two yearling badges on the same day?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104465/two-yearling-badges-on-the-same-day/104469#104469) but the math doesn't parse as described.

Comment: You get a badge for each multiple of (200rep / 1 year). You probably didn't have 200 rep on your first anniversary, but now you have enough for two.

Comment: @muru Hmm. That makes little sense to me as "My history page indicates no activity prior to May 14th here on U&L."  Is the history page inaccurate? I count 7 months.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/104469/270345

Comment: Ok I see on http://stackexchange.com/users/3732749/elder-geek?tab=accounts that I joined U&L 2 years ago. so that must be the value in use (rather than the 2 years 7 months on my profile page)

Comment: no, it's using the 2 years 7 months value alright. See the Meta SE post I linked above, where that user was also active for 2 years + some months.

Comment: Hmm.2 7/12*200=516.666666667 but 2*200=400 and I'm at 402 here.... The math doesn't parse as in the answer linked.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. You don't need to have been active a year ago, you just need an account at least a year old and with enough rep to qualify as active -- your account is 2 years old, so you need at least 2(200) + 1 = 401 rep, which you just made. You could make an account, do nothing for a year, and then get 200 rep in one day and you'd get the badge.
2. You got the badge for the main Unix and Linux site, and again for meta because the rep is shared; that's why the logo is greyed out on one of the notifications

Comment: Thank you for your response. So the fractional year no longer applies as noted in http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104465/two-yearling-badges-on-the-same-day/104469#104469 ?

Comment: @ElderGeek I'm not sure; that answer was posted by a Stack Exchange employee so I would expect it to be accurate, but it doesn't look that way based on what you said, and a bunch of comments on [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188731/145982) have similar stories

Comment: I guess the reasons will remain a mystery without a code review. I have no doubt that everyone involved is providing information to the best of their knowledge and I don't expect more than that. On a related note, I got the same dual yearling badge on askubuntu.com today, and it shows one greyed out as you indicated in your answer but the U&L notifications don't as seen [here](http://imgur.com/D8u9Z6U)

Comment: @ElderGeek The U&L icon is greyed out, it's just harder to tell. [Zoomed in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hz8t7.png)

Comment: Thank you, I'm not sure how I missed that. Interesting color palette choice...