# "Yearling" badge on Unix&Linux meta without any activity and reputation points only from a week before the badge

Tags: support, badges

[image]
I have just earned the "Yearling" badge although I did not do anything on meta, I did not even vote on a meta question or comment or even open it at all. I did indeed earn > 200 reputation in a year but that does not make me a meta user. The meta membership is attached to the main platform like on any other Stack Exchange, that is clear, but without any activity, I did not think to get any badges at all. Now it is >250 on the main platform, with the last rep a week ago, that cannot be the reason.

Is this a mistake?

Comment: I think you get the badge if you simply have enough rep (which you do), based on https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4273/double-notfication-on-yearling-badge-is-this-a-bug-or-am-i-missing-something. I'm not sure why your main & meta accounts got the badge on separate timelines, though.

Comment: @JeffSchaller Perhaps it is about the first visit on meta? Perhaps, I have clicked on it once. I got the Yearling batch on the main account right after reaching the 200, I think.